# Mean of experiment results is the maximum likelihood estimator only when the distribution of error is gaussian.

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

We want to find parameter $\mu$. So we have done some experiments. Let the error of measurements be i.i.d. Prove the mean of the results is the maximum likelihood for $\mu$ only when the distribution of errors is Gaussian (let the distribution of error be differentiable as much as necessary).

Comment: A classic problem, so I wonder *where* exactly do you encounter trouble? Did you try *anything* at all?

Comment: I am a math student with no background in statistics, so it wasn’t an easy question for me. I wrote the equation for maximum likelihood function but I couldn’t get the result that the error should have gaussian distribution. Proof of reverse is easy. When I write the pdf of gaussian in the ML equation, it turns out the mean.

Comment: I'd say go ahead and edit your question and include the material from your comments back into your question post.